Which distance sensor to use to measure the depth of a river?
I am a beginner in embedded systems and I'm working on a project to measure a river's depth over a period of hours or days. I have an ESP32 microcontroller and I'm considering using the JSN-SR04 ultrasonic sensor because it is water-resistant.
My plan is to hang a box over a bridge that will house the sensor and the microcontroller to measure the river's depth. Do you have any suggestions or improvements for this setup?
I welcome any reading materials or resources that could help with this project.

check out books about water, dams and generating power from water. floats in tubes are one idea.
